# Manipulating Multiple word string in bash array

Tags: bash, array

I have got a simple script as follows.

```
names=("windows" "ubuntu" "raspbian" "debian" "kali linux")
echo "names array length: ${#names[@]}"

for n in ${names[@]}; do
    echo $n
done
```

My intention and hope to get was:

```
names array length: 5
windows
ubuntu
raspbian
debian
kali linux
```

but instead the result i got was:

```
names array length: 5
windows
ubuntu
raspbian
debian
kali
linux
```

The array seems to have the correct number of entry but printout appears on 6 lines instead of 5. How can i have the desired output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Double quoting the variable expansion `${names[@]}` would make it expand to the elements of the array, *individually quoted*.  Not quoting that variable expansion would make the shell split all elements on whitespaces (by default), and additionally perform filename globbing on all the generated words (not an issue with the words that you use). In your example, this would cause `kali` and `linux` to be treated as two separate words.

Therefore, use

```
for name in "${names[@]}"; do
    printf '%s\n' "$name"
done
```

or, for this simple script,

```
printf '%s\n' "${names[@]}"
```

(no loop required since `printf` will simply reuse its format string for each individual argument)

Related:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)

Also (why I always use `printf` for outputting variable strings):

- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)